# Como habilitar todas las opciones de Azure DevOps - Pipelines

Tags: azure, cloud, pipeline, devops

Buen día, tengo el siguiente inconveniente, en Azure DevOps, en la pestaña de pipeline me aparece solo 3 opciones que son pipelines, enviroments y library

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero deberian salirme mas opciones pipelines, enviroments, releases, library, task groups, deployment groups y xaml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿saben que cual puede ser el error? Que debe tener mi organización, proyecto o repositorio para que aparezcan las opciones faltantes